# Geoflutterfire Query instead of CollectionReference error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, geofirestore

I have been updating my libraries and flutter version, where I got this error for Geoflutterfire. It says in the documentation that it is possible to use a Query instead of a CollectionReference. The Widget Geoflutterfire require a type of CollectionReference, which the query is use is not.

```
final geo = Geoflutterfire();
final center = geo.point(latitude: MyApp.userLocation.latitude!,longitude: MyApp.userLocation.longitude!);
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;  
var queryRef = await _firestore
                .collection(COLLECTION_JOB)
                .where(IS_ACTIVE, isEqualTo: true)
                .where(IS_DELETED, isEqualTo: false);
    
 var stream = await geo
        .collection(collectionRef: queryRef)
        .within(center: center, radius: NEARBY_JOB_DISTANCE, field: GEO_HASH);
```

In the above code my collectionRef: queryRef won't run as I get this error: "The argument type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CollectionReference<Object?"

It is a simple problem and I tried to change the type to *var* instead of *Query*, where the code ran and gave me this error:
"E/flutter (30258): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_JsonQuery' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference<Object?>'
E/flutter (30258): #0      getGeoHashQuery (package:Hyree/data/firestore/queries.dart:33:34)"

I hope you can help me as the documentation says it is possible:
https://github.com/awaik/GeoFlutterFire
Under the chapter: Scale to Massive Collections

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the current [reference documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/geoflutterfire/latest/geoflutterfire/Geoflutterfire-class.html) and [code](https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/blob/master/lib/src/geoflutterfire.dart#L8-L11) of the `DarshanGowda0 / GeoFlutterFire` library its `collection` method only accepts a `CollectionReference` and not a query.

It seems the [documentation stating otherwise](https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire#scale-to-massive-collections) is wrong here, so you might want to file a bug for that.

Comment: Yeah that is what I would think initially, but I had it working before.

I think I have found the answer in the issue:
https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/issues/172

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to downgrade the version of GeoFlutterFire to version 3.0.1 and Cloud Firestore to version 2.5.4.